# Using SQR to generate a Saved PDF document

Tags: pdf, peoplesoft, sqr

I am using an older client/server version of PeopleSoft (7.53 Apps, 7.63 Tools) and trying to get my SQR to automatically generate and save a PDF document.  Currently I can use a SQR Flag of -ZIV to open up the SQR Viewer which displays my output to the Viewer on the screen, but I have to print to CutePDF Writer to generate the PDF and save it with a PDF extension.  So the process is manual for me.

Is there any way to do this automatically through changing the SQR or using a command line action?

Answer (score 0):

There is a command line parameter to generate a PDF.  It is -printer:pd
Add that to your SQR Flags and it will produce a PDF.

You can also use the SQRWP utility to take a .SPF file (generated with -keep flag) and convert it to PDF.

Comment: I tried the -printer:pd and it didn't produce a file?  Where would it be located?  It did create a SPF file but I'm not sure how to use SQRWP to convert it automatically?

Comment: Also I was able to create a PDF using the -printer::pd (with 2 colons) but it produced a PDF that is unreadable.  The program error says "PDFLib (Fatal): Couldn't read metrics for font Courier"?

Comment: 2 colons means you're running it not in DOS but through the application.  I'm not sure about the error though.  Could be that Acrobat reader has to be installed on wherever the program is running.

Comment: I'm running it to the client and have Acrobat Reader on my machine?  Still it's creating an unreadable PDF and the program errors out with that same error.

Comment: The only other thing I can think of is that SQR is not including the subfolder for Acrobat in the execution string or that Acrobat is not in your system folder list.  Finally, I searched for that error and it seems that PDFLib is a non-Adobe product.  It could be that it's trapping calls to PDF behind the scenes.  Do you have PDFLib installed?  If so, can you run on a different machine that doesn't have it installed.

Comment: Hi @Paul, I've faced the same error that you faced since one year ago: "PDFLib (Fatal): Couldn't read metrics for font Courier" did you reach to its fix? Appreciate any help you can provide.